# Monte Carlo integration for a random integrand (or a set of integrand)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, monte-carlo

I understand that the Monte Carlo integration works for a fixed function, say $$\int f(x)p(x)\mathrm{d}x\approx\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf(X_i),$$ where $p$ is a probability density function on sample space $\Omega$, $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N\sim p$, and $f$ is the integrand.

However, what if we have a family of functions parameterized by $\theta\in\Theta$, and we select the function to integrate based on the samples we got. Let $X^N$ denote $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N)$. Suppose that we have a mapping $g:\Omega^N\to\Theta$. I am interested in the connection between $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf_{g(X^N)}(X_i)$ and $\mathrm{E}_{X\sim p}[f_{g(X^N)}(X)]$. Notice that the former is a sigle-sample Monte Carlo approximation of
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{E}_{X^N\sim p}\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf_{g(X^N)}(X_i)\right]=\mathrm{E}_{\theta}\left[\mathrm{E}_{X^N\sim p}\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf_{\theta}(X_i)\middle|g(X^N)=\theta\right]\right],
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
while the latter is a Monte Carlo approximation of
$$\mathrm{E}_{\theta=g(X^N)}\left[\mathrm{E}_{X\sim p}\left[f_\theta(X)\right]\right].$$

Therefore, the former is a Monte Carlo approximation of the latter when
$$\mathrm{E}_{X^N\sim p}\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf_{\theta}(X_i)\middle|g(X^N)=\theta\right]=\mathrm{E}_{X\sim p}\left[f_\theta(X)\right]=\mathrm{E}_{X^N\sim p}\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f_\theta(X_i)\right].$$

I want to quantify their relations even when this does not hold.
In particular, I am interested in bounding the deviation of $\sum_{i=1}^Nf_{g(X^N)}(X_i)$ from $\mathrm{E}_{X\sim p}[f_{g(X^N)}(X)]$. In general cases, the deviation is unbounded. I believe some extra conditions are needed. So, what kind of extra conditions do I need? Are there some research papers on this topic? I notice that this is related to empirical processes which generalize Monte Carlo approximation to a set of functions. However, I don't know much about this for now.

A specific example is as follows.
Let $p_{\theta^*}$ be a probability density function of a multinomial distribution with parameter $\theta^*$. Let $\Psi_\delta(X^N)$ be an L1 confidence interval with confidence level $\delta$. We select the $\theta\in\Psi_\delta(X^N)$ such that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f_\theta(X_i)$ is minimized, i.e., $\theta=g(X^N)\in\arg\min_{\theta\in\Psi_\delta(X^N)}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f_\theta(X_i)$. To be concrete, let $f_\theta(X)=p_\theta(X)$.

Can someone please help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to specify the problem better. In that generality it will not work. Example: If the sample contains an element larger than one select function A otherwise select function B. But function A is zero for all inputs larger than one ...

Comment: @gg You are right. I listed an example at the end of the description.

Comment: It is still quite unclear what you mean by $\mathbb E_\theta[\cdots]$, since $\theta$ is not a random variable in the question.

Comment: @Xi'an It is a random variable since $\theta=g(X^N)$.

Comment: @Xi'an Here, we assume the integrand is selected deterministically, but it can be generalized a bit such that the integrand is selected randomly, i.e., $g(X^N)$ is a distribution on $\Theta$.

Comment: It does not always converge: a counterexample is as follows: take $\Theta=\Omega$ and $g(X^N)=X_N$, then$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf_{g(X^N)}(X_i)$$does not converge. On the other hand, if $g(X^N)$ is converging almost surely to a constant $\theta_0$, [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#propB3) is likely to be enough to conclude to the convergence to $\mathbb E[f_{\theta_0}(X)]$.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for your help! Is it possible to identify the rate of convergence?

Comment: If a CLT hold for the random sequence$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf_{\theta}(X_i)$$then the rate is the same when $\theta$ is estimated by $g(X^N)$.